# HOw to change the text in a PDF in a different file using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a file (input.pdf) that has a rectangle which is color filled and some some Text ( of a particular Font and size) centered in the rectangle. I want to create another PDF (output.pdf) that looks exactly like input.pdf in every detail( font colour size positioning etc )except the text needs to change( All the text will change so there is no searching involved.
Can I do this using iTextSharp

Comment: I see that already 2 people voted to close your question as "too broad". Your requirement calls for "AcroForm" technology. One would expect that the colored rectangle with the text is an AcroForm text field. In that case, changing the text is only a matter of changing the value of that field. How to do that has been explained dozens of times on StackOverflow. If the rectangle isn't an AcroForm field, you should tell us if it's an option to make it an AcroForm field. That would make your assigment simple too. If you can't make it a field, your question is too broad to answer here.

Comment: It is not an acro form field and I cannot make it an acro form field

Comment: In that case, I'll also vote to close the question as "Too broad".

Comment: See the FAQ: StackOverflow isn't a site where you ask "show me how to do this." StackOverflow is a site where you say: "I have done this to achieve this. Now I have a problem: I get that instead of this. How do I fix this?" You can fix your problem by (1.) showing what you've done so far and explaining why it doesn't work. (2.) fixing your requirement. Your design is seriously flawed. You should use AcroFields, but you don't. You completely ignore the intro of [chapter 6 of the documentation](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf).

Comment: @Rahul you should at least provide your input.pdf for analysis. There are so many different ways the content you refer to may be constructed and depending thereon your requirement may be easy, difficult, or even impossible to implement.